# Difference between () and {} in match structure

Tags: rust

When I want to do nothing in a Rust match structure, I can do either of the two following ways:

```
match some_number {
    1 => println!("One"),
    2 => (), // unit value
    _ => {}  // ?
}
```

Is there any difference? `{}` is not the unit value, so what does it do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`{}` is an empty scope that returns the unit value. They are both semantically the same, just as those 2 functions are identical:

```
fn foo() {}

fn bar() {
    ()
}
```